# Jackson ObjectMapper & JsonGenerator - is it thread-safe?

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I currently have a project which uses jackson faster xml to serialize/deserialize POJOs to Json using custom serializers and deserializers. From what I understand, the ObjectMapper is thread-safe once it has been created and configured. However, I have noticed when running tests with JMeter that occasionally the following can happen -

- Thread 1 enters CustomerSerializer and starts to serialize
- Thread 2 enters CustomSerializer, interuptting Thread 1, and starts to serialize from start to finish
- Thread 1 resumes, and the last thing being serialized is missing

It seems to be that the JsonGenerator instance is being reset when the second thread has entered - surely this shouldn't be happening? I have checked several sites and threads to see if there are any settings or features I need to set, but from what I understand the ObjectMapper reuses JsonGenerator instances, could this be the issue?

The following is a snippet from my custom serializer...

```
@Override
public final void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

    ... Code here ....

    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();

    closeJsonGenerator(jsonGenerator);
}
```

And an example of where it is used

```
SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();
sm.addSerializer(new myCustomSerializer());
new ObjectMapper().registerModule(sm)
                  .writeValue(new myObject());
```

Comment: Please show us how you are using the `ObjectMapper` and `JsonGenerator`.

Comment: Added a snippet of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jackson's `ObjectMapper` creates a new `JsonGenerator` on each request for serialization. In that sense, it is guaranteed to be thread safe. The only thing that I can see that might cause the behavior you are seeing is if your `CustomSerializer` has some instance fields that it is sharing and is doing some kind of internal synchronization.

Comment: I will need to take a look at the code (its for a work project), as fasr as I remember there is no where that the JsonGenerator is being shared. However, from what I can see from debugging through the code, the same instance of the CustomSerializer is returned each time?

Comment: @SCassidy1986 That's normal. You're explicitly creating the instance and passing it when registering the module. (Unless you aren't using the same `ObjectMapper` everywhere.)

Comment: I am using the same ObjectMapper - so I'm guessing that each time the CustomSerializer is invoked it's not creating a new JsonGenerator, but rather passing in the same one each time? Or am I getting how the JsonGenerators are created/reused mixed up in my head

Comment: @SCassidy1986 I think you are confusing them. Any call to `ObjectMapper#writeValue(..)` will internally create a new `JsonGenerator` and use it. That makes it thread safe. On the other hand, it seems like you are using a single `CustomSerializer` so that is possibly shared between threads.

Comment: Yes, since we use the same instance of the ObjectMapper it is reusing the single instance of the serializer, which appears to be the problem. Is there a way to tell the ObjectMapper to create a serializier each time, rather than cache it and reuse?

Comment: @SCassidy1986 Depending on the use case, you can annotate the field/method you want to serialize with `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)`